# Differences between System V ABI and C++ Itanium ABI

Tags: c++, linux, abi

Can anyone help me clarify the differences between System V ABI and C++ Itanium ABI?

As far as I understand, System V ABI sets up conventions how to make syscalls and interact with hardware,  and C++ Itanium ABI is just conventions for C++ programs to link and communicate with other programs, it has nothing to do with syscall or the underlying hardware. Does this sound right?

Comment: @erik258 C++ Itanium ABI is just a mangling convention and has almost nothing to do with the Itanium ISA. [What is the "C++ ABI Specification" referred to in GCC's manual?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52903807/995714), [What are all the commonly used C++ ABIs and mangling schemes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70051283/995714), [Are System V ABI and Itanium C++ ABI related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76044345/995714), [Why does x86-64 use IA-64 C++ ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53455855/995714). [System V ABI](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI) is also not System V

Answer (score 0):

An ABI specifies data layout, calling conventions, program structure, stack unwinding, and more...

The SysV ABI defines all these for C data and functions. It incorporates by reference the Itanium C++ ABI for C++ data and functions.

Comment: Do you mean the hardware implements the System V ABI for C language to follow?

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that the System V ABI defines how C programs should use the hardware (and it covers more than just hardware). The implementors are compilers and linkers. For example, it says that a C function returning an int on x86-64 returns the value in %rax. C compilers have to produce assembly or machine code that returns the value in %rax.

Comment: Why is it that System V ABI defines for C? I can see any compiled language that follows the ABI should work just fine.

Comment: The System V defines how C constructs should work. Parameter passing for struct types, integer types, etc. Other languages which want to "follow the ABI" have to define how to map their language constructs to those in C. For example, only some C++ types are laid out like they would be in C. And so the Itanium ABI has to say which types are laid out like in C, and how the remaining types are laid out. Rust's enum types have no corresponding notion in C, so similarly, one has to define how to map them to C to use the SysV abi.

Comment: Oh in C/C++, the return value is in ran it is because they follow the System V ABI?

Other compiled language compiler can define their own rule of which register to use for return value, and can generate assembly code that does it right?